# Apache reverse proxy and infinite loop

Tags: wordpress, apache, reverse-proxy

I have Server A and B. Server A hosts the main site www.example.com, Server B hosts another site using the subdomain test.example.com. On Server A I set up a reverse proxy, so that the Wordpress site running on test.example.com can be accessed via www.example.com/test

Now I want the subdomain test.example.com to be "invisible" for the user, so that a request to test.example.com will redirect to www.example.com/test.
Obviously, this got me into an infinite loop. I tried different things to break the loop to no avail.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.example.com
  RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) www.example.com/test
</VirtualHost>
```

Add the above apache conf and restart apache.